# Point set registration by minimizing the maximum distance between corresponding points

Tags: euclidean-geometry, transformation, point-cloud

There are two sets with the same number of N 2D points (A, B), N is a small number, usually between 4 to 6. I want to find a rigid transformation (R rotation and t translation), which maps A over B by minimizing the Euclidean distance between the corresponding points. There is a pre-determined correspondence between the points.
Based on hand made examples, if there are N points, at least between two point pairs must be the same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.